# Terraform circular dependency between services

Tags: terraform

I'm just starting learning terraform and am trying to setup an elastic search cluster with an API gateway in front of it.   I've successfully built the service such that the Elastic Search cluster is built and the output endpoint is passed into the API gateway for the integration request via output variables.

In my initial trials I was using wide open access in the `aws_elasticsearch_domain.my_name.access_policies` for testing my template code.  This worked fine for testing purposes but for real world use I want to use the ARN of the API gateway in the `aws_elasticsearch_domain.my_name.access_policies`.  This is problematic seemingly because the `aws_api_gateway_integration.my_name.uri` needs the `aws_elasticsearch_domain.my_name.endpoint` to setup the but `aws_elasticsearch_domain.my_name.access_policies` needs the `aws_api_gateway_deployment.my_name.execution_arn`.

I'm guessing this is fairly common but I can't figure out how to achieve this through outputs or variables.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get around this is by creating a route53 endpoint for your elastic search and hard coding the route53 endpoint of elastic search in API gateway there by breaking the circular dependency.

Comment: Thanks Monil.  This could work but I've run into a different problem in that AWS won't let you have a security policy that allows your API Gateway to talk directly to Elastic Search without making it open to the world.   Their solution is to either proxy it or use a Lambda in a middle both of which are not ideal but there's not much I can do until AWS allows for a direct secure communication.

Comment: Ah yes. I do not like that requirement either. However, using Lambda you can put your resources behind VPC and just have lambda talk to the VPC. Here is the link if it helps
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-gateway-with-vpc-endpoints-via-aws-lambda/

Comment: Thanks Monil.  I now have a Lambda in the middle I just wish I didn't have to since it's adding enough of latency > 100ms in most calls for doing really nothing other then letting me skirt around the odd security restriction in AWS.  But for now it will have to do and I'm hopeful Amazon will add the same security models they have for things like DynamoDB for example in the future so I can go back to API Gateway->ElasticSearch directly.   Thanks again though!